# Combining columns within a single file using awk

Tags: awk

I am trying to reformat a large file.  The first 6 columns of each line are OK but the rest of the columns in the line need to be combined in increments of 2 with a "/" character in between.

Example file (showing only a few columns but have many more in actual file):

```
1       1       0       0       1       2       A       T       A       C
```

Into:

```
1       1       0       0       1       2       A/T     A/C
```

So far I have been trying awk and this is where I am at...

```
awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5; for(i=7; i < NF; i=i+2) print $i+"/"+$i+1}'  myfile.txt > mynewfile.txt
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
awk '{for(i=j=7; i < NF; i+=2) {$j = $i"/"$(i+1); j++} NF=j-1}1' input
```

Comment: `$j` rewrites the value of the jth column. The code only changes columns >= 7. For these columns it concatenates the columns i and i + 1 using `"/"` as the delimiter. The assignment to NF controls how many columns will be printed.

Comment: The block `{$j = $i"/"$(i+1); j++}` is the one repeated 7 to NF times, right? What about the last 1 in `}1`?

Comment: Right, starts from 7 goes up to the last column (`NF`). The last `}1` is short for `print` (awk will print the row if the block returns a true value).

Answer (score 3):

Please try this:

```
awk '{print $1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6" "$7"/"$8" "$9"/"$10}' myfile.txt > mynewfile.txt
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify in my post, but I have more than 10 columns in my actual file.. Actually I have more than a million columns so I need some way to perform that combining pattern until the end of the line.  All of the lines have the same number of columns though.

Answer (score 1):

"+" is the arithmetic "and" operator, string concatenation is done by simply listing the strings adjacent to each other, i.e. to get the string "foobar" you'd write:

```
"foo" "bar"
```

not:

```
"foo" + "bar"
```

Anyway, try this:

```
awk -v ORS= '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6; for(i=7;i<=NF;i++) print (i%2?OFS:"/") $i; print "\n"}'  myfile.txt > mynewfile.txt
```